# List<List<?>> and List<List> are incompatible types in java

Tags: java, generics, casting, raw-types, unbounded-wildcard

I did not get this code to compile either way:

```
List<List> a = new ArrayList();
List<List<?>> b = new ArrayList();

a = b; // incompatible types
b = a; // incompatible types
```

It seems that java does not consider `List` and `List<?>` to be the same type when it comes to generics.

Why is that? And is there some nice way out?

## Context

There is a library function with following signature: `public <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> getSubTypesOf(final Class<T> type)`. This works fine for simple types passed as argument but in case of generics the result is not parametrized with wildcard causing javac to complain about raw type. I would like to propagate the result to the rest of my application as `Set<Class<? extends GenericTypeHere<?>>>` but simple cast does not work as I expect.

## EDIT: Solution

Thanks for the answers, here is how I get it working in the end:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
private static Set<Class<? extends GenericTypeHere<?>>> factoryTypes() {
    return (Set) new Reflections("...").getSubTypesOf(GenericTypeHere.class);
}
```

Comment: can you give example code to show how you're calling this?

Comment: Unfortunately, when a raw type is used as a generic type parameter, the specification becomes pretty vague. There is no conversion defined between `List<List>` and `List<List<?>>`. I don't think we know enough about the context here to say if a cast is appropriate but I showed how to do it in the Q&A I linked to.

Comment: @Radiodef, that explain it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this is due to a subtle semantic difference.

```
List
```

This is the raw type of `List`, which equates to `T` being of type `Object`. So it's the same as saying:

```
List<Object>
```

Now, the Compiler knows for a fact, that whatever happens, this is a subclass of type `Object`. And if you do..

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add(new Object());
```

It will work fine! This is because `Object` is the same or it is some derivation of the type.

```
List<?>
```

This is literally *a list of unknown* ([Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)). We don't even know that the subclass of the things in here are of type `Object`. In fact, the `?` type is an unknown type all on its own. It has nothing to do with `Object`! This is why when you try and do..

```
List<?> myList = new ArrayList<?>();
myList.add(new Object());
```

You get a compile time error!

Comment: Saying `List` is *not* the same as saying `List<Object>` -- but you're not the first person on this page to make that claim. Where does this misconception come from? I find it very strange.

Comment: The subset of semantics shared between `List` and `List<Object>` is unrelated to the compilation error, which has to do with a lack of inclusion of raw types in the specification for generic subtyping.

Comment: This does not really answer the question

Answer (score -2):

```
    List<? extends List> a = new ArrayList();
    List<? extends List<?>> b = new ArrayList();
    a = b;
```

works

`Set<Class<? extends GenericTypeHere<?>>>`

would imply 
`Set<Class<YourClass extends AnotherClass<YourClass>>>`
as mentioned in the above wildcard answer

What stops you from using

`Set<Class<YourClass extends AnotherClass>>` to propagate throughout your app?

Comment: This is a comment, but it seems to work in [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/u0bWy7), however if you take OP's *unedited* code, you'll find that it does not!

Comment: No it doesnt. `ArrayList<List<?>> x = new ArrayList<List>();` This is an error.

Comment: That's not equivalent.`ArrayList<List> x = new ArrayList<List<?>>();` works

Comment: `a=b` works but not `b=a` if you read the question, you'll see that what the OP is after is really `b=a`.